# Is there a way to set a route prop in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to navigate to a specific tab in a page, with

```
      this.$router.push({
        name: "AdminNotifications",
        params: { tab: "requests" },
      })
```

so inside the page i can get the param and set the tab:

```
  mounted() {
    const routeTab = this.$route.params.tab;
    if (routeTab) this.tab = routeTab;
  }
```

It works if the current page is not `AdminNotifications`.

But else, there is an error:
`NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current`

So... is there a way to just set the `tab` props, without navigate?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't navigate to a route if you're already there. But, since you're already there, you can just set `this.tab` to the desired value:

```
if (this.$route.name === 'AdminNotifications') {
  this.tab = 'requests';
} else {
  this.$router.push({
    name: "AdminNotifications",
    params: { tab: "requests" },
  })
}
```

---

If the component in charge of navigating is not the same as the one containing `tab`, you could push the `tab` param to the `$route`:

```
if (this.$route.name === 'AdminNotifications') {
  this.$router.replace({
    params: { tab: "requests" }
  });
} else {
  this.$router.push({
    name: "AdminNotifications",
    params: { tab: "requests" },
  })
}
```

And in the page component, replace the "watcher" in `mounted` with a proper watch, which sets `tab` to any truthy value of `$route.params.tab`, dynamically:

```
watch: {
  '$route.params.tab': {
    handler(val) {
      if (val) {
        this.tab = val;
      }
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly you can just do `this.$route.params.tab = "any value"` like any other variable. `this.$route.params.tab` is just a variable like all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was handling this with the `vue-router`.

1. Add one parent component which will contain tabs and a tab content components.
  Your structure can looke like this:
  *tabs/Tab1.vue

  tabs/Tab2.vue

  tabs/Tab2.vue

  Tab.vue*
2. In Tabs.vue paste code below. The component should contain  in the place where you want to display the content of your tabs and router-links to link a specific tab.
  ***Tab.vue***
  ```js
  <template>
    <div class="tabs">
      <router-link to="/tab1">Tab 1</router-link>
      <router-link to="/tab2">Tab 2</router-link>
      <router-link to="/tab3">Tab 3</router-link>
      <router-view />
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  export default {
    name: "tabs",
    components: {},
  };
  </script>
  ```
3. Then fill tabs content components.
4. In your router.js register your tab routes as shown below.
  ```js
  import Tabs from "./Tabs";
  import Tab1 from "./tabs/Tab1";
  import Tab2 from "./tabs/Tab2";
  import Tab3 from "./tabs/Tab3";

  {
      path: "/",
      redirect: "/tab1",
      component: Tabs,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/tab1",
          name: "tab1",
          component: Tab1
        },
        {
          path: "/tab2",
          name: "tab2",
          component: Tab2
        },
        {
          path: "/tab3",
          name: "tab3",
          component: Tab3
        }
      ]
    }
  ```

Now you should be able to navigate a specific tab by router link.

Comment: Well interesting solution but not what I need, because I'm using vuetify tabs

Answer (score 0):

In the file where you define the routes, you need to define the props for each route, something like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "admin-notifications",
    name: "AdminNotifications",
    component: AdminNotificationsView,
    props: r => ({
      tab: r.params.tab
    })
  }
]
```

And then define the prop `tab` in `AdminNotificationsView` assuming that's the component you use to render the view.